# [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators, CrossDomainConnectors]

Tags: weblogic

En una ocasión, envié mensajes de mi dominio a un dominio externo en **WebLogic**. Esto funcionó bien, pero recientemente he tratado de repetirlo pero con otros dominios, ahora no funciona. Ya habilité una confianza entre los 2 dominios, y estoy segura de que mi información de conexión para conectarme con el dominio externo es correcta, porque ya lo hice antes, pero ahora tengo este problema.

```
<Jul 26, 2018 6:52:22 PM CDT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080003> <A RuntimeException was generated by the RMI server: 1031167307
     java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators, CrossDomainConnectors].
    java.lang.SecurityException: [Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators, CrossDomainConnectors]
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.seal(SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.java:484)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.getSealedSubjectFromWire(SecurityServiceManagerDelegate2Impl.java:177)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.getSealedSubjectFromWire(SecurityServiceManager.java:427)
            at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.getSubject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:362)
            at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.acceptRequest(BasicServerRef.java:996)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace>
```

¿Alguien que sepa cómo resolverlo? Gracias.